# Перезагрузка сайта на сервере

Tags: php, apache

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, не знаю куда копать.
Сделал простой сайт который смотрит в базу данных и берет оттуда сайты которые надо проверять на доступность (загружаются ли они), эти сайты вывожу на страницу в ввиде таблицы, там ещё надо сделать чтобы если сайт не доступен то делать оповещение, или письмо на почту или например сообщение в телеграм, но не суть, это сейчас не важно. Сам код проверки будет выполнятся только если какой-то пользователь зайдет на сам сайт и тогда будут идти проверки и в случае чего оповещать, но как сделать чтобы не надо было заходить на сайт, а он как-то сам на сервере раз в некоторое время обновлялся и как бы код выполнялся заново. Надеюсь доступно объяснить, спасибо.

Comment: Это вам надо копать в сторону js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через планировщик задач **cronBat** раз в какое-то время это любое время которое больше минуты, запускайте скрипт который будет делать проверку. Данный демон(Cron) есть почти на каждом хостинге.

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это то, что нужно